# Flutter box decoration in a container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I use svg image in a container's box decoration? Seems it only allows the png/jpg files in AssetImage(). I am trying to display two images on top of the background image set through the box decoration. I am trying to dodge the method of stack. So is there a way?

Comment: you have to create your own custom `Decoration` class (`class SvgDecoration extends Decoration { ...`)

Comment: Can you help me with this?
`Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/bg.svg'))
              ),
            ),`

Comment: you cannot use `BoxDecoration` - instead you have to write your own custom `Decoration` class

Comment: @pkink Yes, but how do I do it. I am pretty noob with this thing. Can I get a code snippet? XD

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bbfbf1770c/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart#L76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter has no inbuilt support for SVG as of now..

But you can try this package -> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

```
final Widget svg = new SvgPicture.asset(
  "assets/image.svg",
);
```

*However, I'd recommend not using an SVG, instead convert your image to a png format*

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if it helps or face any difficulty